# When viewing man pages in Terminal, how to get correct man page order priority? `man` shows the correct manpage but Terminal shows an older one

Tags: terminal, bash, homebrew, zsh, command-line

I love using the Terminal's man page viewer.  You can right click on anything and open its corresponding man page. Or just run `open x-man-page://1/<man page>`

However, I'm having trouble getting Terminal to prioritize the right man page over a pre-installed one.  Specifically it's the man page for the newer version of `rsync` installed by homebrew.  Running `man rsync` in a shell shows the correct rsync manpage, from `/usr/local/share/man/man1/rsync.1`, but using Terminal's manpage viewer shows the man page for the old version of rsync from `/usr/share/man/man1/rsync.1.gz`.

A very temporary solution is to run Terminal like this:

```bsh
$ MANPATH=/usr/local/share/man /System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal
```

That starts Terminal with `MANPATH` set and it then looks in the right spot to find the new rsync man page. But setting MANPATH overrides all the other smart ways of finding man paths.

Note that the issue only shows up when there's multiple man pages for the same command.  Somehow `man rsync` knows to prioritize the man page installed by Homebrew in `/usr/local/share/man` but Terminal prioritizes `/usr/share/man/`

I tried editing `/private/etc/man.conf` and to `/usr/local/share/man` first, but it had no effect.  Even commenting out all the `/usr/share/man` references had no effect.

Any ideas how to get Terminal's `x-man-page://` to prioritize the right man page like just running `man` does? Cheers!

Comment: Try putting `export MANPATH=/usr/local/share/man:$MANPATH` in your .profile or .bashrc or whatever your shell needs.

Comment: @lhf The trouble with this solution is that `MANPATH` is already undefined and this defines it.  Defining any `MANPATH` disables the "smart" man path finding that `man` already does.  With my `MANPATH` empty it finds manpages is a variety of locations.  Running `man -w -a "*"` will list every man page and doing `man -w -a "*" | sed -E "s/\/[^\/]*$/\//g" | sort | uniq` reveals that there's 57 uniq man page directories on my system. I want to keep using the "smart" man path finding and not have to enumerate every one (since they often change)

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering this too. I couldn't find a direct solution that was better than your workaround of setting MANPATH before launching Terminal.app.

An alternative workaround is to use `man`, as that's giving you the correct page, and the `open` command to view the man pages in TextEdit instead of Terminal's view. This can be wrapped in a function (and set in `~/.bashrc`) for easy access, e.g.:

```bash
mano() { MANWIDTH=100 MANPAGER='col -bx' man "$@" | open -f; }

# use with e.g.
mano rsync
```

Depending on your default settings in TextEdit, this can give a nice view, with the good search function etc. You can also open the man page in a browser by adding `-a <application\ name>` after the open command. E.g. for Google Chrome:

```bash
mano() { MANWIDTH=100 MANPAGER='col -bx' man "$@" | open -f -a Google\ Chrome; }
```

tip source: [scripting osx](https://scriptingosx.com/2017/04/on-viewing-man-pages/)